# How to implement error handling?

Tags: error-handling, autoit

My AutoIt script generates an error that I want to handle. A way that any error goes to a custom function will also do. In VBA I use `OnErrorGoTo`, but I am unable to find something similar in AutoIt.

My Code :

```
Func Start()
    While 1
        If ProcessExists ( "Photoshop.exe" ) <> 0 Then
            Sleep(5000)
        Else
            Local $sFile ="C:\Auto\CodeToBe\Batch\Image Process-50-2D v.2-" & $n & ".jsxbin"
            Local $iPID = ShellExecute($sFile)
            Sleep(10000)
            $n = $n+1
        EndIf
    WEnd
EndFunc
```

An error will occur when `$n` exceeds the number of files in that folder. I tried this but didn't work (from the "HELP SECTION" and a forum post):

```
Global $iEventError = 0 ; To be checked to know if COM error occurs. Must be reset after handling.
Local $oMyError = ObjEvent("AutoIt.Error", "ErrFunc") ; Install a custom error handler

Func Start()
    While 1
        If ProcessExists ( "Photoshop.exe" ) <> 0 Then
            Sleep(5000)
        Else
            Local $sFile ="C:\Auto\CodeToBe\Batch\Image Process-50-2D v.2-" & $n & ".jsxbin"
            Local $iPID = ShellExecute($sFile)
            If $iEventError Then
                MsgBox($MB_OK, "", "There was an error on the previous line.")
                $iEventError = 0 ; Reset after displaying a COM Error occurred
            EndIf
            Sleep(10000)
            $n = $n+1
        EndIf
    WEnd
EndFunc

; This is my custom error handler 
Func MyErrFunc() 
    Msgbox(0,"","ERROR GENERATED ON " & $n)
Endfunc
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50539184/4157124).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debugging an AutoIt script or get currently executed script line number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109244/debugging-an-autoit-script-or-get-currently-executed-script-line-number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend the second example because it prevents an error in the first place. However, the first example can be used as a general error checker.

### Example 1

```
Start()

Func Start()

    Local $n = 1
    While 1
        If ProcessExists("Photoshop.exe") <> 0 Then
            Sleep(5000)
        Else
            Local $sFile = "C:\Auto\CodeToBe\Batch\Image Process-50-2D v.2-" & $n & ".jsxbin"

            Local $iPID = ShellExecute($sFile)
            If @error Then MyErrFunc(@ScriptLineNumber, @error) ;check for error

            Sleep(10000)
            $n = $n + 1
        EndIf
    WEnd
EndFunc   ;==>Start

; error handler
Func MyErrFunc($iLineNumer, $iError)
    $iLineNumer = $iLineNumer - 1
    MsgBox(0, "", "ERROR GENERATED ON SCRIPT LINE: " & $iLineNumer & @CRLF & "ERROR CODE: " & $iError)
EndFunc   ;==>MyErrFunc
```

### Example 2

```
Start2()

Func Start2()

    Local $n = 1
    While 1
        If ProcessExists("Photoshop.exe") <> 0 Then
            Sleep(5000)
        Else
            Local $sFile = "C:\Auto\CodeToBe\Batch\Image Process-50-2D v.2-" & $n & ".jsxbin"

            If FileExists($sFile) Then
                Local $iPID = ShellExecute($sFile)
                Sleep(10000)
            Else ;handle error (you could use a function here if you wanted)
                ConsoleWrite("File not found: " & $sFile & @CRLF)
            EndIf

            $n = $n + 1
        EndIf
    WEnd
EndFunc   ;==>Start2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to implement error checking.

```
If Not FileExists(your string with the $n) Then
    ... abort
Else
    shellexecute ...
```

You could use [`_FileListToArray()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_FileListToArray.htm) instead.

Comment: You do not need to use a COMError Handler for that, I suppose. The error occurs when the shellexecute is called with a non-existing file. That is why I suggested to check whether the file exists before calling shellexecute. That's all.

Answer (score -3):

> An error will occur when `$n` exceeds the number of files in that folder.

As per [Documentation - Function Reference - `_FileListToArray()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_FileListToArray.htm) :

> Lists files and\or folders in a specified folder (Similar to using Dir with the /B Switch)

Will loop over existing filenames only (avoiding error altogether). Example:

```
#include <File.au3>

Global Const $g_sPathFiles = 'C:\Auto\CodeToBe\Batch\'
Global Const $g_sMaskFile  = '*.jsxbin'
Global Const $g_aFile      = _FileListToArray($g_sPathFiles, $g_sMaskFile, $FLTA_FILES, True)

For $i1 = 1 To $g_aFile[0]

    ShellExecuteWait($g_aFile[$i1])

Next
```

Alternatively [`_FileListToArrayRec()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_FileListToArrayRec.htm) may be used.

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50539184/4157124).